# How do you configure a truststore (jssecacerts file) in a spring-ws pox client?

Tags: httpclient, spring-ws

I have a jssecacerts file i need to configure for SSL. Does spring-ws allow you to configure/point to a jssecacerts file? Here is my current configuration, note it is a POX service and not SOAP:

```
<bean id="poxMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.pox.dom.DomPoxMessageFactory" />

<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="poxMessageFactory"/>
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender" />
    </property>
    <property name="defaultUri" value="https://some.com/service"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
</bean>
```